# np.vectorize: signature / axis order

Tags: numpy, vectorization, signature

I have a function, let's say `f: (m),(n)->(n)`, operating on numpy arrays. I would like to vectorize it and apply it to all pairs of **columns** of `a` (shape `(100, 5)`) and `b` (shape `(20, 5)`).

I can do the following:

```
vec = np.vectorize(f, signature='(m),(n)->(n)')
res = vec(a.T, b.T).T  # shape (20, 5)
```

because by default `np.vectorize` seems to loop over the first available axis. But is there a way to directly tell `np.vectorize` that I would like to work on the last axis of both `a` and `b`, to avoid overusing `.T`?

Looking at [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html), I'm not sure there is, but maybe I missed something.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you are trying to replicate `np.array([f(a[:,i], b[:,i]) for i in range(5)])`?  Does '(m,j),(n,j)->(n,j)' work?

Comment: keep in mind that vectorize with signature is not a speed tool.

Comment: `signature` tells `vectorize` what shape of arrays `f` accepts and returns.  It does not tell `vectorize` how to iterate over the larger input arrays.  `np.vectorize` has its own info on `signature`; it may be modelled on the C-API Ufunc, but that shouldn't be taken as the primary documentation.  In either case there isn't any sort of 'axis' parameter.

Comment: If using `ipython` (or other ide) you can check the method that uses the signature with `vec.]: ._vectorize_call_with_signature??`.  While `np.vectorize` may be interesting to explore, it shouldn't be seen as a tool to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am well aware that this is not at all a performance tool, I'm simply using it for conciseness and better readability.